# Tooltips wanted [pure javascript]

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I make this post because a script of pure javascript tooltips, no jquery and other libraries.

There are very few on the web, and there are old and very outdated or move to around the link, as this http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/

But I just want one made with pure javascript and without mobility, like Twitter or Facebook tooltips.

So, I would like to provide me a link that contains a tooltip as I ask or a tutorial.

Thanks very much and excuse my english, i'm from Argentina.

I hope can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like the Twitter tooltips, you're in luck. They're open source, as part of the [Twitter Bootstrap library](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips). You should be able to modify them to not require jQuery fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks, friend, but i really need tooltips without any libraries :S

Comment: You're essentially *asking* for a tooltip library. Take a look at the code for Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips and adapt it to your needs. You don't need to use the whole system.

Comment: To what document? You are likely going to have to do at least a little coding. If you're not comfortable with that, you may have to relax your strict rule on no libraries (which, often, is a bad stance to have - jQuery is very handy in a lot of cases).

Comment: javascript is used, the problem is that distinction which is part of jquery and that part is normal, because I never use jquery

Comment: First, I'd recommend experimenting with jQuery. It makes JS development a lot easier in most cases. Second, yes, that code uses jQuery. You should be able to look at the logic in the code and duplicate it in normal JS.